# Create an algorithm that asks the user for two positive numbers, call them "first" and "last", and prints the sum of all the numbers between first

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a program that I need to compile that does the following:

1.One way to do multiplication is by repeated addition. For example, 47 x 25 can be evaluated as 47 + 47 + 47 + . . .+ 47 (25 times). Sketch out an algorithm for multiplying two positive numbers a and b using this technique.

2.Create an algorithm that asks the user for two positive numbers, call them "first" and "last", and prints the sum of all the numbers between first and last inclusive. Thus, for example if the input was 4 and 7 (this works also if input was 7 and 4), the algorithm will print 22 because 4+5+6+7 = 22

So for the first one I really don't have an idea how to start and I understand that it's simple but I'm new to programming.

For the second problem I wrote this program but there's one error of unexpected unqualified-id right after int main()

```
#include <iostream>
int main();

{

int num1, num2, sum = 0; //Sum starts at 0 and contains the sum of all even numbers

cout << "Enter first integer: ";
cin >> num1;
cout << "Enter second integer: ";
cin >> num2;
{
while (num1 <= num2)

    sum += num1;
    num1++; };

cout << "Sum is " << sum << "." << endl;
cin.get();
return=0;
}
```

I would appreciate any advice as soon as possible

Comment: Start by removing the semi-colon right after int main()...

Comment: `{ while` doesn't look quite right, now does it?

Comment: "I don't know how to start" is not a question for SO. This is a repository of programming gems, not a chatroom.

Comment: Shoot. I don't think they have to be gems, but they have to be something more than what's covered in the first few pages of a programming text book. If basic syntax isn't out of scope, it should be.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't concern the code itself, but rather efficiency: This can easily be solved in constant time. Thanks to Gauss we know:

```
sum from 0 to N is: N * (N + 1) / 2
```

We can simply calculate the sum from first to last using that formula. Simply substract the sum from 0 to first - 1 from the sum from 0 to last:

```
int sum = last * (last + 1) / 2 - (first - 1) * (first) / 2;
```

Thanks to @MOehm for pointing out some mistakes in my answer.

Comment: Good observation, but it was Gauss, not Euler, and the formula is `N * (N + 1) / 2`, at least if `N` is to be included in the sum as in the OP's assignment.

Comment: Now that is a worthwhile answer. Not what OP wanted, but definitely something of which OP should be made aware.

Comment: @MOehm oops. thanks, haven't used this for a while... i'll correct the mistakes

Answer (score 1):

Remove the semicolon after `main()`, prepend `cout`, `cin` and `endl` with `std::` (i.e. make it `std::cout`, `std::cin` and `std::endl`), and remove the `=` in `return=0`.

The code will then compile.